# Using Fody.PropertyChanged, how to use with a property of BindingList<T>?

Tags: c#, bindinglist, fody, fody-propertychanged

I have the following classes using Fody.PropertyChanged weaving:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class OtherClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #pragma warning disable 67
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #pragma warning restore 67

    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #pragma warning disable 67
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #pragma warning restore 67

    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public BindingList<OtherClass> Others { get; private set; }

    public MyClass ()
    {
        Others = new BindingList<OtherClass>();
    }
}
```

From a class consuming **MyClass**, I do not receive a **PropertyChanged** event.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Not familiar with Fody, but from [this example](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), it looks like Fody takes care of the INotifyPropertyChanged for you — try removing the INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance and the event call.  Just a guess.

Comment: @LarsTech, well if I remove the INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance then the consuming class can't subscribe to the PropertyChanged event!

Comment: I'm assuming you are having issues with the `Others` property and not the `SomeText` property?

Comment: @Stécy who (which object) do you expect to raise `PropertyChanged` and with what argument (Property Name)?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I expect MyClass to raise PropertyChanged ("Others") when the binding list content changes (Fody could make the registering of ListChanged event on Others).

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the ListChanged event of the BindingList class to raise the PropertyChanged event:

```
public MyClass() {
  this.Others = new BindingList<OtherClass>();
  this.Others.ListChanged += Others_ListChanged;
}

void Others_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Others"));
  }
}
```

My OtherClass did not have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class OtherClass {
  public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that takes care of propagating the **PropertyChanged** event. This would be nice if Fody would handle this case automatically.  I still need OtherClass to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** since I want other classes to subscribe to the event.

Comment: @Stécy PropertyChanged.Fody is not going to implement this because basically it's wrong. `PropertyChanged` should be raised in case another value is assigned to the property (in your case, another list to the `Others` property). The collection itself should raise events in case the elements of the collection change. So if you need to know whether collection item change you need to subscribe to both, `PropertyChanged` (in case the collection is replaced) and `Others.CollectionChanged` or `Others.ListChanged`

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I understand your point. Thanks for clarifying.